# spring security and angularjs redirecting back to given url after login

Tags: spring, angularjs, spring-mvc, redirect

I have a web application using spring 3.2.The login process is done through spring security.When a user gives a url to view the profile of a particular user he will redirect to login page if he is not logged in.I need to go back to the user's profile if he is not successfully logged in.Since I am using angular js my urls are in the form

http://mydomain.com/#/view-profile/71 to view the profile of the user.If I am not logged in it will redirect to login page.In the browser url becomes http://mydomain.com/login#/view-profile/71 but after successful login it is not redirecting to the specified url.How can I make that with angularjs.

In app.js I have given like this

```
$routeProvider.when('/view-profile/:id',
    {
        templateUrl: '/partials/editor/view-profile.htm',
        action: 'kc.view-profile',
        resolve: {
            loadData: ViewCtrl.loadUserProfile
        }
    }
);
```

And for authentication in security.xml it is written like

```
    <http use-expressions="true">
            <!-- Authentication policy -->
            <form-login login-page="/login" login-processing-url="/j_security_check" authentication-failure-url="/login?error=true"/>
            <logout logout-url="/signout" delete-cookies="JSESSIONID" />
            <intercept-url pattern="/assets/**" access="permitAll" />
            <intercept-url pattern="/application/signin/**" access="permitAll" />
            <intercept-url pattern="/application/signup/**" access="permitAll" />
            <intercept-url pattern="/application/manage/**" access="ROLE_EDITOR" />
            <interce

pt-url pattern="/application/**" access="isAuthenticated()"  />
        <!--<intercept-url pattern="/application/connect/**" access="permitAll" />-->
    </http>


    <authentication-manager alias="authenticationManager">
        <authentication-provider user-service-ref="userDao">
            <password-encoder ref="passwordEncoder"/>
        </authentication-provider>
    </authentication-manager>
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Handling angularjs url in spring security How to redirect back to url with # in it](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20186410/handling-angularjs-url-in-spring-security-how-to-redirect-back-to-url-with-in)

Comment: The duplicate question has been removed by its author.

Answer (score 1):

Spring Security doesn't support Ajax login out-of-the-box, that's why your application isn't working correctly.

You can have a look at this sample application that handles Ajax login/logout with AngularJS + Spring Security:

https://github.com/jhipster/jhipster-sample-app

I had to implement some specific Ajax handlers, as you can see here:

https://github.com/jhipster/jhipster-sample-app/tree/master/src/main/java/com/mycompany/myapp/security

Comment: The sample app that you have pointed out looks really good in case of having a login form within angular. And I really liked the way the http-auth-interceptor scripts work. But I'm trying to find pretty much the same concept except for Spring Security being implemented with a SSO concept like Siteminder. That would be a great help for a lot of folks out there. Thanks ! Really appreciate your work :)